# Estoy teniendo este problema en el Visual Studio Code al tratar de guardar los cambios en el archivo, dice permisos insuficientes

Tags: php, vscode

No se pudo guardar el archivo "" permisos insuficientes. Seleccione ‘Reintentar como Admin’ para volverlo a intentar como administrador.
Alguien que me pueda auxiliar con este problema?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Reintentaste como admin?

Comment: Así es, ya descubrí que es, como es un equipo nuevo debo cambiar el administrador porque según el equipo TrustedInstaller está como administrador. Aún así me permite guardar los archivos, gracias!!!